# how to access event parameters in unit test frame 0.9.12

Tags: rust, substrate, polkadot

Hi all I am trying to access the values passed in the event .

I have extract the event with this -  not this is substrate 0.9.12 so I have not been able to use some of the examples I find online that use substrate 2.0.0

```
let e = &frame_system::Pallet::<Test>::events()[0];
 let EventRecord { event, .. } = e;
```

And this is the structure of event

```
Event::MosaicVault(
    Event::VaultCreated {
        sender: 1,
        asset_id: A,
        vault_id: 1,
        reserved: Perquintill(
            1000000000000000000,
        ),
    },
)
```

How do I access vault_id value , a sample would be helpful , thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is called destructuring of enum (if you want to search online for more example).

Basically you can use some `match` or `if let` to get the inner fields of some variants of enums.

something a bit like this:

```rust
if let Event::MosaicVault(Event::VaultCreated { vault_id, .. }) = event {
// here you have access to vault_id
}
```

Comment: Links to the relevant sections of the docs: [`match`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/ch06-02-match.html) and [`if let`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/ch06-03-if-let.html).